# Creating a linked list of unique elements

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a school work where I need to use lists in Java and insert words from texts files, and exclude the similar ones. I'm trying to make it so the new element will only be added to the list in case it doesn't equal an existent one, but it keeps adding the element regardless.

My method inside the class List to insert a new element in alphabetical order

```
public void inserirOrdem( String elemento ) {
        No novoNo = new No( elemento );
        No actual = cabeca;  //actual=head of the list
        No anterior = null;
        // look for place where to add new element
        while( actual != null && actual.item.compareTo( elemento ) < 0 ) {
        anterior = actual;
        actual = actual.prox;
        }
        if(!elemento.equals(actual.item)) { //so that the new element won't be added if there's an equal one.... doesn't work
        novoNo.prox = actual;
        if( anterior == null ) //in case the list doesn't have any elements
        cabeca = novoNo;
        else
        anterior.prox = novoNo;
        nElementos++;
        }
}
```

My node class:

```
private class No{

    No prox;
    String item;

    No( String elemento ) {
        item = elemento; 
        prox = null; 

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest writing a method `public boolean contains(String elemento)` that returns true if the string is already in the list and false if it is not.

Comment: oh! will try changing that!

Comment: Created a new method in List class 

public boolean checkSimilar(No a, No b) {
  return a.item.equals(b.item);
 }
and changed the if statement to if(!checkSimilar(novoNo,actual)), still doesn't work

Comment: I'm trying to make it not add an already existing element to 'optimize' the code. It works if Iook at the lists elements beforehand, but I wanted to overlook that and apply the condition on the insert method directly.

Comment: guys, don't answer homeworks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution, although I recommend testing it further. I don't have your original LList class, so I'm using a static version which should be easily adaptable to your needs.

```
class Main {

    /* Inserts a node into a unique, alphabetical list */
    public static No inserirOrdem(No cabeca, String elemento) {
          if (elemento == null) { return cabeca; }
          if (cabeca == null) { return new No(elemento); }

          No novoNo = new No(elemento);
          No actual = cabeca;
          No anterior = null;

          // valid entry to add at beginning of list
          if (cabeca.item.compareTo(elemento) > 0) {
              novoNo.prox = cabeca;
              return novoNo;
          }

          while (actual != null && actual.item.compareTo(elemento) < 0) {
              anterior = actual;
              actual = actual.prox;
          }

          // valid entry to add at end of list
          if (actual == null) { 
              anterior.prox = novoNo;
              return cabeca;
          }

          // valid entry to add in middle of list
          if (actual.item.compareTo(elemento) > 0) { 
              if (anterior == null) {
                  cabeca = novoNo;
              }
              else {
                  anterior.prox = novoNo;
                  novoNo.prox = actual;
              }
          }

          return cabeca;
    }

    /* Prints a linked list */
    public static void p(No head) {
        No c = head;

        while (c != null) {
            System.out.print(c.item + " -> ");
            c = c.prox;
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        No head = new No("a");
        No b = new No("b");
        No d = new No("d");
        No e = new No("e");
        head.prox = b;
        b.prox = d;
        d.prox = e;

        System.out.println("Original:");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add duplicates:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "a");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "b");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "d");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add c in the middle:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "c");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add f at the end:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "f");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add h at the end:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "h");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add g in the middle:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "g");
        p(head);

        head = null;

        System.out.println("Null head, add a:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "a");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add null str:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, null);
        p(head);

        head = new No("c");

        System.out.println("Try to add duplicate:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "c");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add a at beginning of list:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "a");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add z at end of list:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "z");
        p(head);

        System.out.println("Try to add f at middle of list:");
        head = inserirOrdem(head, "f");
        p(head);
    }
}

class No {
    No prox;
    String item;

    No (String elemento) {
        item = elemento;
        prox = null;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Original:
a -> b -> d -> e -> 

Try to add duplicates:
a -> b -> d -> e -> 

Try to add c in the middle:
a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> 

Try to add f at the end:
a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> 

Try to add h at the end:
a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> h -> 

Try to add g in the middle:
a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> g -> h -> 

Null head, add a:
a -> 

Try to add null str:
a -> 

Try to add duplicate:
c -> 

Try to add a at beginning of list:
a -> c -> 

Try to add z at end of list:
a -> c -> z -> 

Try to add f at middle of list:
a -> c -> f -> z ->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Set collection. It doesn't allow any new element that is already equal to one that is in the set. Just need to implement the equals method in your No class.

See [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/set.html), but there are many examples in google.

Cheers.

Comment: I think @Andreia have to specifically use List as mentioned in the question itself,